# Время в котором наибольшее количество запросов Apache

Tags: linux, apache, bash

Есть log-file Apache. Как с помощью bash получить инфу в каком часу было наибольшее количество запросов?

Comment: Покажите ваше решение и задаёте вопросы по нему

Comment: или хотя бы несколько строк из лога, чтобы было понятно, как извлечь из этих строк часы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, что-то типа такого http://www.monitorware.com/en/logsamples/apache.php

Comment: Всем спасибо, сделал я с помощью awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с помощью программы *bash* это будет сделать довольно трудоёмко.

проще будет воспользоваться более подходящими инструментами — например, программой *sed* для извлечения нужных двух цифр из каждой строки:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/\1/' /путь/к/файлу/с/логом
```

затем программой *sort* для сортировки и программой *uniq* (с опцией `-c`) для подсчёта уникальных значений:

```
$ sed ... | sort | uniq -c
```

---

например, для первого из блоков, приведённого [по этой ссылке](http://www.monitorware.com/en/logsamples/apache.php) результатом будет две строки:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*/\1/' /путь/к/файлу/с/логом | sort | uniq -c
     27 16
     23 17
```

показывающие, что в 16 часов было 27 строк, а в 17 часов — 23 строки.